# pip install pyarrow failed on Linux ppc64le

Tags: python, cmake, pip, pyarrow

**I am using Python 3.7 and PIP 21.0 and linux ppc64le.**

When i try to install pyarrow with pip it errors out with below error message. Can some one please help

-- Could NOT find Arrow (missing: Arrow_DIR)
-- Checking for module 'arrow'
--   No package 'arrow' found
CMake Error at /home/***/miniconda3/envs/myenv/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:218 (message):
Could NOT find Arrow (missing: ARROW_INCLUDE_DIR ARROW_LIB_DIR
ARROW_FULL_SO_VERSION ARROW_SO_VERSION)

### -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/pip-install-eupzn03_/pyarrow_3ebdc9313f8c40db9a823ba34e4a40e0/build/temp.linux-ppc64le-3.7/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
error: command 'cmake' failed with exit status 1

ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue you are seeing here is because you haven't yet installed the Arrow C++ libraries. You first need to install them and then install/build `pyarrow` itself afterwards.

For `ppc64le`, there are no `pyarrow` wheels available. If you can use `conda` instead, we are building `pyarrow` conda packages on conda-forge.

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion. When I do conda install pyarrow -c conda-forge , conda shows lot of incompitable packages due to which installation do not work. Before pyarrow I also installed pytorch. (with channel pytorch , early-access).  Can you please suggest how can i come out of this issue ?

Comment: Try using `mamba` instead of `conda` for the package installation. This should work exactly the same but `mamba` gives you a better error message.

Comment: mamba could not able to help .. My original probelm ... I want to install pip install datasets .... this failes with pyarrow could not build. and Conda install datasets gives package inconsistency ... hence I am not able to move further